# On Safari 11, youtube iframe autoplay works on one page but fails on others, same iframe code

Tags: iframe, safari

This one has me stymied. It's the same iframe code, except of course for the video ID itself. Autoplay works on one page but doesn't on others. All the iframe options are the same; it's built automatically for every page by a PHP script on the site.

Here is a link to the page where the autoplay is working: http://www.theidahoclub.com/

And here is a link to a page where the autoplay does not work: http://www.theidahoclub.com/real-estate/

All pages work correctly on Edge and Chrome. Any ideas?  Is there a developer tools equivalent on Safari so I can grab some more debug info?  I'm not a Mac owner, but I have someone with the setup where it reproduces, so they can test for me (but they don't develop so they wouldn't know about Mac dev env stuffs).